# If for $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ $e^{A}$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove that if for $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, $e^{A}$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ is diagonalizable. I don't even know how to start, what tools should I use?

Comment: The obvious candidate for a diagonalization of $ A $ would be tmy he same as that of $ exp (A) $ but with the logarithm of diagonal elements

Comment: Are you familiar with Jordan decomposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put $A$ into Jordan form.
2. $exp$ acts on each block of the Jordan form.
3. Now show that if the exponential of a Jordan block is diagonalizable, then the Jordan block had to be 1x1. You can explicitly compute the exponential of a Jordan block, and compute its minimal polynomial. If the original block wasn't 1x1, the polynomial of the exponential of the block has repeated roots, so it isn't diagonalizable.

In 3 we use that a matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial has distinct roots. This can be proved using the Jordan canonical form, also.

When you are looking for a tool to study matrices over $\mathbb{C}$, it is probably Jordan normal form.